# iOS audiobook player with sleep timer and bookmark support

Tags: audio, ios, audiobook

I’m searching for an audiobook player for iOS.

This player needs to support:

- Audiobooks in MP3, AAC, M4B without DRM
- A sleep timer (e.g. set to auto-stop after 30 minutes)
- Placing bookmarks

The built-in audio player does not support bookmarks, or a sleep timer. The [Audible app](http://www.audible.com/mt/Apps) can see the books and supports bookmarks, but the sleep timer doesn’t work. All the apps I see when I search for "audiobooks" in the app store seem to be tied to a DRM bookstore or website.

I have a copy of [Little Brother](http://craphound.com/littlebrother/) and I got the audiobooks from the last and current [Humble Audiobook Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/books).  There doesn’t seem to be a good way to play these on my iPad. I’m hoping there is some audiobook app that is hidden in the store and just not showing up in my searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bookmobile](http://freshmowed.com/bookmobile.html) or [Bookmower](http://freshmowed.com/bookmower.html) seem to be what you're looking for. I haven't used them, but based on their descriptions in the App Store and their website, seems that they have all the features that you're looking for. The former supports podcasts as well. They seem to be free for a limited time only, but it's always worth to pay for the apps one needs that would make life easier for them!

Comment: Those certainly look promising.  They appear to be 'free', with an in-app purchase ($2.99) to enable full functionality, which is certainly fine for me if it works properly.  I'll certainly be testing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try [MP3 Audiobook Player Free](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mp3-audiobook-player-free/id891797540) .
Very simple and useful application. Supports MP3 and M4B audiobooks. Has bookmarks and timer. In Appstore there is a free version (with 12h duration limit and ads) and a pay version without any limitation.
Books can be uploaded over iTunes or browser on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[Undulib](http://undulib.com) does all of that, except placing bookmarks. It will remember your last playing position.

-Take this suggestion with a grain of salt. I am the developer of [Undulib](http://undulib.com).

Comment: Looks interesting - it's not clear however how you import books into the app. Does it read only the ones uploaded via iTunes, or does it also support cloud services such as Dropbox?

Comment: Only reads iTunes libraries. If it shows up in iBooks, it will appear in Undulib. I might add cloud service support later...